# ssh command doesn't source export envvars

Tags: linux, ssh, environment-variables

I have a remote bash script (in `/home/web/web/scripts/setenv.sh`) in charge of exporting environment variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SYMFONY__ENV__MAILER__USER=noreply@mydomain.com
```

On a local machine, I wish I could ssh to that remote machine and execute a command. That command should first setup the environment variables and then use them in the command (here, I just print it) :

```
ssh web@mmachine.mydomain.com "source /home/web/web/scripts/setenv.sh && echo ${SYMFONY__ENV__MAILER__USER}"
```

The result of the echo is an empty string.

I also tried this, but this yields the same result :

```
ssh web@mmachine.mydomain.com "/bin/bash -c '. /home/web/web/scripts/setenv.sh && echo ${SYMFONY__ENV__MAILER__USER}'"
```

Why does the echo doesn't print `noreply@mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh web@mmachine.mydomain.com "source /home/web/web/scripts/setenv.sh && echo ${SYMFONY__ENV__MAILER__USER}"
```

This evaluates the variable in your local shell. To evaluate the variable in the remote shell, you should pass the command in the single quotes:

```
ssh web@mmachine.mydomain.com 'source /home/web/web/scripts/setenv.sh; echo ${SYMFONY__ENV__MAILER__USER}'
```

It should do the job. At least minimal reproducer works for me:

```
$ ssh machine 'VAR=test; echo $VAR'
test
```

Comment: Thank you Jakuje. Using 'VAR=test; echo $VAR' works properly, but setting the VAR variable in the /home/web/web/scripts/setenv.sh file and sourcing it doesn't work, even enclosing the whole thing with single quotes. I need to source the file because it contains dozens of envvars I do not want to pass explicitly and manually with affectations. Any other idea ?

Comment: Not the difference between `;` and `&&`. In case the last command executed in your sourced file returned non-zere exit code, your echo is not even executed.

Comment: The file you `source` needs to be on the remote machine.

Comment: @erik Yes, the file is on the remote side, in /home/web/web/scripts/setenv.sh, the file is chmod +x and is executed (in add an echo in it, and it is displayed)

Comment: @jakuke : the last command in the sourced file is an export

Comment: Ok guys forget it. I'm ashamed, and I'd like to hide in a hole. I mispelled the environment variable...

Comment: Though the need of the single quotes still persists. Good to hear it worked :)

Comment: Yes, I've just confirmed this, accepting your answer right now ! Thank you for your help ! To me the string was just passed to the remote bash and then expanded/executed there, didn't thought it could be interpreted locally first !